# react material UI modal content should be another URL

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Is it possible to pass a URL into the material-ui Modal/Dialog to set its content? if not, how would you suggest I go about this? I have a page which I would like to load into a dialog. I don't want it to be a component as I want it to have its own URL.

Comment: Are you trying to show URL content in the modal popup? Like, show the content in an Iframe.

Comment: Yes - I would like to show the content in the modal. Is iframe the only way to go?

Comment: Depends on how you will get the HTML content. If you have the code of the URL you are talking about in a separate URL, yes Iframe is the only option. If you have an HTML file in your code you can use either an Iframe or dangerouslySetInnerHTML. The latter is not a safe option.